# windows service DbResource Provider

Tags: c#, windows, service, localization, globalization

I am developing a Windows Service with c# 3.5 and want to store language specific resource strings within SQL Server and access them via a DbResourceProvider.  All the examples I have seen however do not show how to set the resource provider within a Windows service (they all show specifing the provider within a web.config file).

How can I set the resource provider within my Windows service ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no `DbResourceProvider` in the framework itself... so which one are you using ?

Comment: I think he is referring to http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2010/06/25/extending-resource-provider-for-soring-resources-in-the-database.aspx

Comment: @ChrisShain thanks :-) this basically means he can't use it in a Windows Service... for a Windows Service something similar can be done but with a different interface etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `DbResourceProvider` is based on the interfaces `IImplicitResourceProvider` and `IResourceProvider` - both interfaces reside in the namespace `System.Web` for a reason: they are specific for ASP.NET. They are NOT intended for use in non-ASP.NET scenarios (like Windows Service, WinForms etc.) !

The way to do something similar for non-ASP.NET scenarios is to implement your own `IResourceReader` and use it in a class derived from `ResourceManager` - an example with source code can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14136/Custom-Resource-Reader).